# Is there a way to "subscribe" to a question and get notification?

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, follow-post

Sometimes I find a question interesting. I then add it to my bookmarks.

However, if someone posts an answer or a comment to this question, I am not notified automatically via my inbox (***in the way I would be notify if someone answers/comments to my own question***). Is it possible to "subscribe" to a question in this way?

Comment: "Follow" option